# release bug，Object cannot be cast to androidX.lifecycle.ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, generics

```
//BasePagingFragment.kt
abstract class BasePagingFragment<T : Any, Vm : BasePagingViewModel<T>> :
    BaseViewFragment<BaseFragmentPagingListBinding>(R.layout.base_fragment_paging_list) {
...other code
    open fun createOpenViewModel(): Vm {
        return createViewModel(getViewmodelKey())
    }
...other code
}
```

//ViewTop.kt

```
fun <VM : BasePagingViewModel<*>> BasePagingFragment<*, VM>.createViewModel(key: String? = null): VM {
    val vmClazz1: Class<VM> = getVmClazz1(this)
    val newKey = key ?: "com.paging" + vmClazz1.javaClass.simpleName
    return ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(this.requireActivity().application)
    ).get(newKey, vmClazz1)
}

inline fun <reified VM> getVmClazz1(obj: Any): VM {
    val genericSuperclass = obj.javaClass.genericSuperclass
    return (genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[1] as VM
}
```

Many of my pages have implemented the BasePagingFragment class, but in the online environment,only some pages  will report errors, and the exact reason cannot be found so far
How can I troubleshoot and solve this problem, can you help me

No error will be reported if the obfuscation function is not enabled.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.Object cannot be cast to androidX.lifecycler.viewModel